# Uncountable sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

i need help with a mathematics for computer science assignment question.. I have no idea where to start and if someone could guide me in the right directon it would be great. thanks for you your help and time.

Give an example of two uncountable sets A and B such that A – B is

(a) Countably Infinite.

(b) Uncountable.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: For both examples you can take $A=\Bbb R$. For the first one: start with a countably infinite difference set and work backwards to get $B$. For the second one, think about this diagram of $\Bbb R$:

```
        ---------------------|--------------------
```

Comment: Another way to think about problem (a). If $A=\mathbb{R}$, what happens if $B=\mathbb{R}\setminus {\{1\}}$? Or if $B=\mathbb{R}\setminus {\{1,2\}}$? Or $B=\mathbb{R}\setminus {\{1,2,3\}}$?

Answer (score 0):

For (a) something like $A=[0,1]$ and $B=$set of irrationals in $[0,1]$ can work.

For (b) $A=[0,1]$ and $B=[0,1/2]$ can work.